# SQL Server INSERT-OUTPUT including column from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to insert data into a table and I need to output the newly inserted ids from the destination table mapped alongside the Ids from the source table.
I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @mapping TABLE(
            DestId int,
            SourceId int);


INSERT INTO dest_table (column1, column2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id as DestId, src_table.Id as SourceId   INTO @mapping 
SELECT 
    src_table.column1,
    src_table.column2

FROM src_table
```

Which gives the following error:

```
The multi-part identifier "src_table.Id" could not be bound.
```

Normally, I would use a `MERGE` statement.  However in this case it has to run on SQL Server 2005!!!

Is there any way of achieving this without resolving to a cursor and inserting values one by one?

Comment: You can't access the columns not part of the insert, unless you're using MERGE which i don't think is available in SQL Server 2005, you have to join them back by using some way of identify stuff, or use some hacks like re-purposing columns for IDs

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo.  The table is `src_table1` (with the `1` at the end) whereas the aliasing is using `src_table` (without the `1` at the end).  Can you just add the alias to the table?

```
DECLARE @mapping TABLE(
            DestId int,
            SourceId int);


INSERT INTO dest_table (column1, column2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id as DestId, src_table.Id as SourceId   INTO @mapping 
SELECT 
    src_table.column1,
    src_table.column2

FROM src_table1 src_table
```

Comment: Ooops, thanks for pointing that out! The typo was only in my question though!  The table is actually meant to be src_table. It is still an issue with the corrected table name.  I have edited my question.